# Ubuntu root cannot log in because of mistake made manually editing etc/password

Tags: login, password, password-recovery

I am a new user of Ubuntu. I mistakenly changed the `etc/password` file because it was showing duplicates user error while deleting one user.

Now it's not possible to log in with root user/password. I am using Cloud Hosting of linode Hosting. I am not resetting root password from the linode.com panel. I am scared I to need shutdown the server first and all running services will also stop, and if after reset login might not work and I will not be able to restart the services.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Can't linode help with this issue?

Comment: Restore a backup from your access page on the cloud.  And if you do not have one delete this instance and make a new one. Making mistakes on a cloud instance is bad. Not having a restore point is the end of your system. I would start making a backup of your personal files. And make a habit of making backups.

Comment: @GeorgeUdosen I did't create support ticket there, I am creating ticket there for help.

Comment: @Rinzwind I dont know how to fix that issue, I know the issue that I made. But Now i am not able to login at Shell/FTP how I can fix that issue.

Comment: When you work with online instances you --must-- have a backup made before you start editing configuration files When you lock yourself out you basically kill your system. The generic method would be: dis-attach your instance from your dashboard at the cloud instance website, create a new instance, mount the old system inside your new system and fix your problem. Re-attach your old system and boot it.

Comment: @GeorgeUdosen Thanks, I solve the issue by taking help from  linode